4-pin SMD component identification, -6+ 85G
[
Need help identifying this board component

-6+ 85G is what I see printed on it

Change your question title to "4-pin SMD component identification, '-6+ 85G'". That way someone who knows the answer might be tempted to open your question and reply. It will also help anyone with a similar question browsing through search results. Don't bury relevant information in the comments. [Edit] it into your question. Welcome to the forum!

Is this in a power supply section? First guess because of the +/- symbols is a full wave bridge rectifier.  Also, replace the photo showing the area around the part as this could be a clue.

Changed title, thank you for the tip.

I will try to supply a better photo for more context

@DavidL Is there a component identifier on the board next to that part? What do those two large solder connections on the lower side of the part in the photo connect to?

It's a Vishay MB6S bridge rectifier.

The is no description in the datasheet about what the characters other than the 6 mean, but comparing different pictures on LCSC, they seem to be a traceability code.

(MB6S-E3/45)

(MB6S-E3/80)

(MB2S-E3/80)

much appreciated that looks like an exact match, I've uploaded a new photo to show a new component, not sure if that's the correct way, very new to this

No, revert the photo back and open a new question. If someone comes along later you don't want them getting confused.

@DavidL I rolled back the change for you. Never change a question to a completely different one after it has been posted.

Understand, I have posted a new question. Sorry guys
